# Tower of Hanoi (Recursive)

Tags: java, recursion

I'm looking through Introduction to Java Programming Comprehensive 9th Edition and I have a question about recursive functions and counters. How would I add counters to this program? I.e. How can I make the program print out what turn it is when it prints out the movie it has to make?

EXAMPLE OUTPUT

Turn 1 Disk 1 to C

Turn 2 Disk 2 to B

Program:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int n = 3; // Number of disks

        System.out.println("Tower of hanoi with " + n + " disks");

        TowerHanoi(n, "A", "B", "C"); // Space A is the initial position, B is the storage position, and C is the final destination

    }

    public static void TowerHanoi(int numDisk,String towerStart, String towerStor, String towerDest) {

        if (numDisk == 1) { // Moves disk 1             
            System.out.println("Disk " + numDisk + " to " + towerDest);                 
        }

        else if (numDisk != 1) {

            TowerHanoi(numDisk - 1, towerStart, towerDest, towerStor); // Moves a disk from the starting tower to the destination tower

            System.out.println("Disk " + numDisk + " to " + towerDest);

            TowerHanoi(numDisk - 1, towerStor, towerStart, towerDest); // Recursive call, moves disk from storage to destination                
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Am I assuming correctly that the book has not yet discussed objects and therefore you do not know, how objects work? If so, there is one general approach: Redesign the singature of the method, give it an additional parameter. Then modify the body of the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that easiest (but somewhat hacky) solution is adding static variable to Test class, like

```
public static int turn = 0;
```

and printing it in TowerHanoi function before each of two "println" calls

```
System.out.print("Turn " + turn++ + " ");
```

Comment: This leaves you (the programmer) with the issue of incrementing and decrementing turn (you have to decrement it again before leaving a recursive call). It would be easier to add a parameter, since the parameter has "only" to be incremented.

Comment: I agree that this is not the best solution possible. However as I see from code it eventually prints "Move" message on every call, so if you add counter before that print message (in both places) you should get correct output (given that you expect all moves to be numbered in incremental manner)

Comment: Thank you, I'm sorry if my question was ambiguous, I was simply asking about having a counter for this specific design.